# Angular 6: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError triggered from select drop-down event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-bootstrap

> **What code changes can remedy the Error described below ?**

**Use-case**

A drop-down input UI is protected from unintended selected value change via a modal. However, the event (click, focus or other), wired to the drop-down causes the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, observed in Chrome console in dev mode.

**Observed result**

When drop-down is clicked, an **ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError** is thrown (see console)

**Expected result**

When drop-down is clicked, a Modal opens without error

**Demo**

A link to demo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zaggi-angular-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-v1-in)

***Notes***

- As described in "Everything you need to know about ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4), I attempt to trigger change
  detection (see comments inside app.component.ts:48-49, marked as
  STEP-1 and STEP-2), but unsuccessfully (probably triggered not in the right place?)
- The modal in the demo is not fully implemented for [OK] and [CANCEL] as it doesn't affect the Error
- The code is simplified version of a larger app

Comment: I see two things about the `select` element that you may want to change. (1) You use `ngModel` and `[selected]`, use only `ngModel`. (2) Instead of processing the `(click)` event of the dropdown, I suggest using one-way binding with `[ngModel]` and handling `(ngModelChange)="processValueChange($event)"`, where you could do some checking before confirming the change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **What code changes can remedy the Error described below ?**

The code like this should help you:

```
<select 
  [(ngModel)]="building.venueId"
  #ngModel="ngModel"
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  get hold of NgModel instance
  ...
  (click)="ngModel.control.markAsTouched(); confirmChangeItem(building.venueId)">
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           and prepare FormControl to the changes
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbykgv?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

**Update**

I forgot to say that you can remove `cdRef.detectChanges` and microtask in this case so i'm glad to know you guessed it yourself

Comment: Neat stackblitz [link] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/zaggi-angular-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-v2-fi) with unused Change detection and micro/macrotask code removed, based on the valuable inputs from @yurzui

Comment: Thank you so much! I struggled with this for hours before finding this answer!

Comment: I am very curious to know why this is even necessary.   I have code that doesn't update the form, and merely opens a modal, and this error occurs unless I use the markAsTouched work around.